# OnNavigatedTo Event show no suitable method found to override C# UWP

Tags: c#, events, uwp, frame

My `App.xaml.cs` when I put the `OnNavigatedTo` Event show me **"no suitable method found to override"** I don't know why, but I want anyone help me please because I search in a lot of places and don't get information about this error.

```
namespace Notepad
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Proporciona un comportamiento específico de la aplicación para complementar la clase Application predeterminada.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Inicializa el objeto de aplicación Singleton. Esta es la primera línea de código creado
        /// ejecutado y, como tal, es el equivalente lógico de main() o WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Se invoca cuando el usuario final inicia la aplicación normalmente. Se usarán otros puntos
        /// de entrada cuando la aplicación se inicie para abrir un archivo específico, por ejemplo.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Información detallada acerca de la solicitud y el proceso de inicio.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // No repetir la inicialización de la aplicación si la ventana tiene contenido todavía,
            // solo asegurarse de que la ventana está activa.
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Crear un marco para que actúe como contexto de navegación y navegar a la primera página.
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Cargar el estado de la aplicación suspendida previamente
                }

                // Poner el marco en la ventana actual.
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // Cuando no se restaura la pila de navegación, navegar a la primera página,
                    // configurando la nueva página pasándole la información requerida como
                    //parámetro de navegación
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);

                }
                // Asegurarse de que la ventana actual está activa.
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Se invoca cuando la aplicación la inicia normalmente el usuario final. Se usarán otros puntos
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Marco que produjo el error de navegación</param>
        /// <param name="e">Detalles sobre el error de navegación</param>
        private void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        protected override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnFileActivated(args);
            var rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args);
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        protected virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Se invoca al suspender la ejecución de la aplicación. El estado de la aplicación se guarda
        /// sin saber si la aplicación se terminará o se reanudará con el contenido
        /// de la memoria aún intacto.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Origen de la solicitud de suspensión.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Detalles sobre la solicitud de suspensión.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Guardar el estado de la aplicación y detener toda actividad en segundo plano
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add behavior which doesn't exist into an Application instance.
The Application class is responsible for encapsulating an app singleton and provide specific services, such as :

> - app entry point, particularly for various activation contracts
> - app lifetime management
> - app-scoped resources
> - unhandled exception detection

Events such as the `Navigated` are exposed by a `Frame` object, and therefore if you want to be notified when the so called rootFrame performs the navigation for its initial page, you should have it subscribed to the Navigated event, on the `OnLaunched` event handler.

```
rootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigatedTo;
```

Now you could add your event handler as such,

```
void OnNavigatedTo(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Navigating to the initial application Page!!!");
}
```

But the main point, is that if you want to handle events regarding your navigation process, either *Navigating*, *Navigated*, *NavigationStopped*, and *NavigationFailed*, you have to understand that those are logic encapsulated onto a Frame object.

In order to create a content that a `Frame` can navigate onto, you create a class which inherits from the [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) class, which basically encapsulates content, that you can navigate onto utilizing a `Frame` instance.

Snippet from Microsoft's documentation:

> You can override the page OnNavigatedTo, OnNavigatingFrom, and
>   OnNavigatedFrom methods to perform tasks such as initializing and
>   saving the page state.