# WPF event if page is navigated to

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

### Description

In my WPF C# project I have multiple pages that are navigated to using the
navigation service.
Some of them are not always new instances, but rather saved to then be loaded again on the next navigation to it.

This leaves me with the problem that the variables inside do not reset when the page is loaded again.

### What I have tried

In my first WPF project I just grabbed the Instance before navigating to it and reset all of the required variables manually.
This is probably the simplest but most redundant solution, since I have to add this functionality before each navigation.

Now I tried just detecting whether a page is navigated to.
With that I could just add a method to reset all of the variables that is automatically called if the respective page is navigated to.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420775/onnavigatedto-event-show-no-suitable-method-found-to-override-c-sharp-uwp) solution on Stackoverflow.
Though when trying to implement into my Settings page, it leaves me with the error:

> "Settings.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs)": No suitable method found to override

Further research lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420775/onnavigatedto-event-show-no-suitable-method-found-to-override-c-sharp-uwp) solution.
When implementing this line into my MainWindow.cs:

```
NavFrame.Navigate += OnNavigatedTo;
```

the following error occurs:

> The Name "OnNavigatedTo" does not exist in the current context

### Question

What is either a fix for my chosen approch OR what is another approach to detect such an event for my kind of purpose?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Comment: Would have been a better idea to use viewmodel first navigation and just new up an instance rather than resetting values. Maybe a bit late now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you should be able to handle the `Loaded` event for the `Page` to detect when it is being navigated to in WPF:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // reset state here...
    }
}
```